# How to increase count of a formula

Tags: excel

Please help me to increase count in below row formula ..

```
=David!F31
```

I want the formula to be like as shown below but when I drag its increasing the alphabets instead of number.

```
=David!F31  =David!F32  =David!F33  =David!F34  =David!F35 =David!F36
```

Kindly advice.

Regards

Comment: drag it down! not across  ( or else use the function INDIRET & COLUMN to work out the offsets

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using the indirect function:

```
=INDIRECT("David!F"&COLUMN()+24)
```